# Required State not working in Checkout

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, requirejs, state

I need the state to be a required field in the checkout page so I set it in the Admin Panel
[image]

But it is not working. How can I fix this one? I am using Magento 2.1.6
[image]

Comment: Please clear  cache and deploy static content again

Comment: @AmitBera I already did that

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a core bug, you can view the info on the ticket raised [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5279).

Magento say:

> This issue has been delivered to 2.1.3, 2.0.10 as well as 2.2.0

But other people say this is not the case.

Comment: Saw and read it. It seems that there is no work around for this bug yet.